# Change the mailto: in \href

Tags: hyperref, languages

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
This works fine:
\href{mailto:exmaple@example.com}{exmaple@example.com}\\
I would like this to open the default e-mail program:
\href{eposta:exmaple@example.com}{exmaple@example.com}
\end{document}
```

and output

[image]

This is because "E-mail" is "E-posta" in Turkish.

Comment: What is your question? I don't get it. Do you want to open the default email software if somebody clicks on the link?

Comment: This is most likely the default text `Acrobat Reader` and perhaps other views show by default if the mouse is over a mail address. I don't know whether this is changeable at all

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, yes. Exactly true.

Comment: I think that your code is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Özgür: So you want `hello:exmaple@example.com` to cause an email client to open?

Comment: @Werner, PDF file error. `Error when getting information for file '/tmp/latexila-Z4I84X. No such file or directory` And default e-mail software not open.

Comment: @Özgür: Why `hello`? Is that what you want in the subject of the email?

Comment: @Werner, I wrote an example. That I want `E-posta`, because `E-mail=E-posta` in my language. I want, whole Turkish Language in my document.

Comment: @Özgür: That is *system-dependent* and has nothing to do with a language preference. The "currency of negotiation" for most programming languages is English, since it's universal.

Comment: @Werner, thanks for all reply message. The question is stopped.

Answer (score 18):

I think you misunderstood something here.

Package `hyperref` is designed to add a clickable link into the internet to allow to open a special website or to open a mail program to send an email to the defined address.

A computer, exactly an operating system (Linux, Unix, OS x or Windows), can do this only if the information is provided which protocol is used for this service.

So an URL has to be something like that:

> protocol://domain.top level domain or email@address

The protocols are `http` (web side), `https` (secure connection to website), `mailto` (email) or `ftp` (down- and uploads with ftp server) and others, named in the rfc files. `hello` is there not named!

Examples:

- `http://tex.stackexchange.com`  The url for this site
- `https://tex.stackexchange.com` Secure connection to this site
- `mailto://example@example.com` Send email to adress `example@example.com`.

The operating system can now start -- after knowing the protocol -- the corresponding program.  For `http` etc the used internet browser, for `mailto` the installed email program. Both, browser and email program are different for different OSs and users.  Nevertheless, protocol `mailto` is known by each operating system, your wanted `hello` **not**.

That you have to click on that link is a thing of security, or do you want to get a pdf, filled with thousands of virus containing web pages or other bad thing, and all of them are opened when you open the pdf file to read it?  I do not want this, I think you do too?

Comment: Is there `//` in a mailto?

Answer (score 8):

Since this has been revived I will add that the visible part can be any phrase you like including E-posta (It is only the tooltip for protocol) that should not/cannot change.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
You can show a link in any language or wording you want

However the mail protocol is ``mailto: (with or without //)''
\newline
These work fine:

\href{mailto:example@example.com}{E-posta: example@example.com}

\href{mailto:example@example.com}{e-posta: example@example.com}

\end{document}
```